# Systemd resource management via CGroup

Tags: linux, systemd, cgroups, resources

I want to know how can I limit ( or eliminate any limitation for ) the resource consumption (i.e CPU and memory usage ) of systemd slices via `CGroup` ?

There's a command named `systemd-cgtop` which prints out the current resource usage by slices , but is there any command to exert a limitation ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

systemd uses cgroups to implement resource control. I don't know anything about slices, but you can find a bunch of options for all kinds of units [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html).

FYI I haven't had much luck using MaxMemory= but LimitAS=/LimitDATA= work [almost as well](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#LimitCPU=) if you have the same issue (and I'd be interested to know if you do).